# how to use one animation in different div in angular 4? is it possible?

Tags: angular

this is my animation code

```
[
trigger('slideInOut', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
  ])
])
```

]

i need to use two div ,when one div is false second div want to follow the animation ?
any help?
my html code is

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="show_chart" [@slideInOut]>
    <label>New One</label>
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="show_chart" [@slideInOut]>
    <label>Second one</label>
</div>
```

only first div is displaying

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: I think it is not problem of angular animation so once check this step without *ngIf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the *ngIf, The proper syntax of animation is below,

```
animations:  [
  trigger('slideInOut', [
    state('1', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    state('0', style({ opacity: 1 })),
    transition('1 => 0', [
      style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
      animate('300ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
    ]),
    transition('0 => 1', [
      animate('300ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
    ])
  ])
]
```

and in html write as following ways

```
<div>
  <div [@slideInOut]="!show_chart">
    <label>New One</label>
 </div>
 <div [@slideInOut]="show_chart">
    <label>Second one</label>
</div>

<button (click)="show_chart = !show_chart">Toggle Me</button>
```

As you missed to use **state** in animations.

Use of **state** is use to check the current status.

Comment: i have an array of values let abc =["one","two","three"] depends on this value i create the div.  This array is not consistent,it may be change.  what i want is, when abc[0]== one then div1 want to be displayed ,if it is two another div want to dispaly...It want to be slide one by one